# Returning to a previous choice in python

Tags: python, game-development

I’m working on a text adventure game for my first big self-made project in Python. I’m trying to figure out how to make it so that the player can go back to a previous area so that they may make another choice. I’m not sure how to do that. Any idea how?

```
answer_yes = ["Yes" ,"Y" ,"yes" ,"y" ]
answer_no = ["No" ,"N", "no", "n"]
answer_north = ["North", "N"]
answer_south = ["South", "S"]
answer_east = ["East", "E"]
answer_west = ["West" "W"]



print("""
Welcome to Ziggy's Adventure

You are standing in a field, north of the coast, to your north is a beach, to your west is a dirt path, which way will you go?
""")

ans1 = input(">>")

if ans1 in answer_north:
    print(
        "\n You arrive at the beach, the sound of seagulls and the salty sea air, you can see the beach, "
        "there is nothing much here. Where will you go now?")
    ans1
```

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: You'll be wanting a classic *while True* loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use while loop here.

```py
answer_yes = ["Yes" ,"Y" ,"yes" ,"y" ]
answer_no = ["No" ,"N", "no", "n"]
answer_north = ["North", "N"]
answer_south = ["South", "S"]
answer_east = ["East", "E"]
answer_west = ["West" "W"]


while True:
  print("""
  Welcome to Ziggy's Adventure

  You are standing in a field, north of the coast, to your north is a beach, to your west is a dirt path, which way will you go?
  """)

  ans1 = input(">>")
  if ans1.lower() == 'exit':  # add an if statement if input is exit then exit(break) the loop.
    break

  if ans1 in answer_north:
      print(
          "\n You arrive at the beach, the sound of seagulls and the salty sea air, you can see the beach, "
          "there is nothing much here. Where will you go now?")
```